# Write IdentityServer4 logs to a log.txt file

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core. We want to write Identity Server's logs to an external file (i.g. `log.txt`). Can we do this via the log4net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the relevant IdentityServer docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/logging.html):

> IdentityServer uses the standard logging facilities provided by ASP.NET Core.

So in essence, your question nearly duplicates [this question about hooking up log4net in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46169606/419956). The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805223/419956) for that question also explains how to add a rolling file appender, which is what you'd need to get what you want.

That basically answers your question as currently written. If you need more specific advise, I recommend asking a question with your current attempted code / steps to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: thanks @Jeroen, after i checked the link("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169606/how-to-use-log4net-in-asp-net-core-2-0"), i have the same implementations as described, but i have got the error message on console windonw("log4net:ERROR ConfigureFromXml called with null 'element' parameter")

Comment: I suggest asking a fresh question then that includes an [mcve] so we can easily reproduce your scenario. Otherwise we'd be _guessing_ at the problem.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core has pretty good logging support straight out of the box.

Have a read of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: thanks @mackie, now we are able to show logs on console window, so how can we write those into a text file?

Comment: Looks like there isn't a standard one but plenty of articles out there on how you roll your own.

Comment: and my original question was related to write Identity server's logs into a text file, can we do this in the same way?