# Log4Net on .Net Standard has no version for getting logger without repository

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-standard

I am trying to move a project to .net standard and it basically is a class library. 
I am using log4net for logging and I was using the method

```
public static ILog GetLogger(string name);
```

As this is a library referenced by multiple projects, defining repository should not happen as each project referencing this one, defines it's own repository for logging.
How can I circumvent this issue when it comes to porting to .Net standard?

Comment: You should probably *not* use `ILog`. Use the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` interfaces instead and configure them to use log4net as the actual logger. You *can't* force users of your library to use Log4Net. The logging abstractions have become a defacto standard too, which means NuGet packages support them already

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950113/134204) shows how easy it is to integrate log4net with the logging abstractions. You can then use DI to inject the proper logger to each class and avoid static logger instances

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implementation of `GetLogger` is simple:

```
public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
{
    return GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), name);
}
```

Assuming you want to use your class library's assembly, you can write your own helper method for that easily:

```
private static ILog GetLogger(string name) =>
    LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SomeTypeInYourLibrary).Assembly, name);
```

It's basically hard-coding the assembly to be "the assembly containing the type you've specified" which is what you'd always get from calling `GetLogger(string)` from your library anyway.

Comment: Nice. Jon Skeet delivers once again :)