# Log4net: How to use GetLogger in NET Standard?

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

I am porting my NET Framework application to .NET Core.
I use log4net, installed NuGet package.
But the code worked in NETF version cannot be compiled in NET Standard version

```
static public ILog MainLogger
{
    get
    {
        if (_logger == null)
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(@"MyLibLogger");
        }
        return _logger;
    }
}
```

The error is:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type'

I.e. the log4net does not contain anymore method
LogManager
->GetLogger(String name);

What should I use instead of?

Comment: May be LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyLibLogger)); ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can use my class

Comment: Thanks to Peska, it helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586494/log4net-on-net-standard-has-no-version-for-getting-logger-without-repository